# Gstreamer audio capture on file

Tags: audio, gstreamer, audio-recording

i'm new to Gstreamer and basically have been reading the documentation for a day now. I need a program that captures audio from an audio input for 10-15 sec every 5 mins and stores it into a file. 
The only thing i have no idea how to do is the capture itself, since i haven't worked with inputs before. Now i found this code on the net but have no idea if it will help me (i understand most of it but have no idea where does it save the files, if it saves them at all) any help would be really appreciated

```
import gi
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

autoaudiosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "audioconvert")
vorbisenc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("vorbisenc", "vorbisenc")
oggmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("oggmux", "oggmux")
filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")
url = "1.ogg"
filesink.set_property("location",url)
pipeline.add( autoaudiosrc)
pipeline.add( audioconvert)
pipeline.add( vorbisenc)
pipeline.add( oggmux)
pipeline.add( filesink)

autoaudiosrc.link( audioconvert)
audioconvert.link( vorbisenc)
vorbisenc.link( oggmux)
oggmux.link( filesink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
Gtk.main()
```

P.S. a professor suggested gstreamer to me, and i haven't found a good alternative, so that's why i'm trying it, but if there is a better way out there please tell me, since i feel like gstreamer is more in a player/ playback nature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the question is nicely written, however you could try out more investigation before you ask.. also you can add tag python and the code would be highlighted..

Anyway gstreamer is perfectly ok for saving to file..

The example saves the output into file called `1.ogg` in current directory where you run the script.
Have you already run the script? look for that file where you ran it..

The filesink element does the actual file saving. If you want to save each capture in another file you could generate some filename in format for example YYYY-MM-DD_HH_mm_ss.ogg(this is typical datetime format where YYYY represents year, MM month etc).

You can either

- run the script every 5 minues if you are on linux thic could be a cron job
- or just a bash script..
- or you can code it in python in same script to run the gstreamer pipe again and again.. this would be harder but 'nicer'

Comment: Found the problem, needed to reinstall ubuntu (for some reason i couldn't get sudo access, no idea what went wrong there)
It saves the file now as it should, and i plan to make a loop of sorts that gives the file a number (21,2,3,4 and so on) Will post it here when i finish the whole thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
import gi
import datetime, time
import sys
import signal  
signal.alarm(15)
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gst, Gtk
GObject.threads_init()
Gst.init(None)

pipeline = Gst.Pipeline()

autoaudiosrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("autoaudiosrc", "autoaudiosrc")
audioconvert = Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioconvert", "audioconv")
audioresample= Gst.ElementFactory.make("audioresample","audioresample")
vorbisenc = Gst.ElementFactory.make("vorbisenc", "vorbisenc")
oggmux = Gst.ElementFactory.make("oggmux", "oggmux")
filesink = Gst.ElementFactory.make("filesink", "filesink")
url = datetime.datetime.now()

audioresample.set_property("quality", 10) 
vorbisenc.set_property("quality", 1)

filesink.set_property("location",url)
pipeline.add( autoaudiosrc)
pipeline.add( audioconvert)
pipeline.add( vorbisenc)
pipeline.add( oggmux)
pipeline.add( filesink)
pipeline.add( audioresample)

autoaudiosrc.link( audioconvert)
audioconvert.link( audioresample)
audioresample.link(vorbisenc)
vorbisenc.link( oggmux)
oggmux.link( filesink)

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

Gtk.main()
```

As promised, the full code. The best audio quality you can have, plus it saves the files as a date and dime now.
As for the storing, i made a bash script that works perfectly, so that solved that (found out that if i do it in the script itself, the file never saves properly)